# Microsoft.Datasync.Client.DatasyncInvalidOperationException: 'There are still pending operations for table 'todo' after a push'

Tags: maui, data-synchronization

I am trying to create a MAUI app with offline data sync.

I am getting the above error on Android emulator when calling the Sync method. The sync runs well when debugging on windows app.
below is my code

```
public async Task SyncAsync()
        {
            if (!_initialized)
                return;

            ReadOnlyCollection<TableOperationError> syncErrors = null;
            try
            {
                //foreach (var offlineTable in offlineTables.Values)
                //{
                var pullOptions = new PullOptions { PushOtherTables = true, WriteDeltaTokenInterval = 25 };
                await table.PullItemsAsync(pullOptions); //Error here...
                await table.PushItemsAsync();

                //}
            }
            catch (PushFailedException exc)
            {
                if (exc.PushResult != null)
                {
                    syncErrors = (ReadOnlyCollection<TableOperationError>)exc.PushResult.Errors;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how I initialize my offline definition

```
private async void Init()
        {
            if (_initialized) return;

            //Create offline definition
            var dbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "todoitems.db");
            //var store = new OfflineSQLiteStore($"file:/{dbPath}?mode=rwc");
            var connectionString = new UriBuilder
            {
                Scheme = "file",
                Path = dbPath,
                Query = "?mode=rwc"
            }.Uri.ToString();
            var store = new OfflineSQLiteStore(connectionString);

            store.DefineTable<ToDo>();
            var options = new DatasyncClientOptions
            {
                OfflineStore = store,
                //IdGenerator = (table) => Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                InstallationId = null,
                //ParallelOperations = 1,
                SerializerSettings = null,
                //TableEndpointResolver = (table) => $"/tables/{tableName.ToLowerInvariant()}",
                UserAgent = $"Datasync/5.0 (/* Device information */)"
            };

            //Create the data sync client
            string baseAddress = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "https://10.0.2.2:7067" : "https://localhost:7067";
            client = new DatasyncClient(baseAddress, options);

            //Initialize database
            await client.InitializeOfflineStoreAsync();

            //Get reference to the offline table
            table = client.GetOfflineTable<ToDo>();
            // Set _initialized to true to prevent duplication of locking.
            _initialized = true;
        }
```

And below is the screenshot of the error:

[image]